# React Native: platform specific import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

Got this weird situation. Building for react native and using a native package from Intercom. Importing it works fine when android or ios. But for the web (or node jest) it throws an error.
So have to do some face-pattern "hacking" like this

> utilities/Intercom/index.ios.ts

```js
export { default } from '@intercom/intercom-react-native'
```

> utilities/Intercom/index.web.ts

```js
export default function Intercom() {}
```

> some file that uses Intercom

```js
// @ts-ignore
import Intercom from '~/utilities/Intercom' // Cannot find module '~/utilities/Intercom' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

...

Intercom.logout() // no TS support
```

Not only does TS complain, but I also loses all types

Is there any other way to do platform specific import and keep the native types?

---

The error in jest (node) is `Cannot read property 'UNREAD_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION' of undefined` which is also described in their [docs](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-react-native#when-tests-with-jest-fail-mentioning-cannot-read-property-unread_change_notification-of-undefined). Problem is that I can't mock it out when using react-native-web that comes with expo.

Comment: Can you share the error? What does the error thrown from node or Jest?

Comment: @VickyAhuja I have updated the question with the errors

Comment: Just asking, have you created jest.mock function inside the "jest/setup.ts" file?

Comment: Yes i have done that. But that jest is not the issue. The issue is that when running the web version via expo react-native-web it tries to call some native code that does not work. So have to overwrite it

Comment: for the web, you can create index.web.ts, have you tried that also?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question or perhaps write it as an answer?

Comment: I really hope the T in this path is a typo only in your question `utilities/Tntercom/index.web.ts`

Comment: yes, thx. that is a typo in the question.

Comment: What are you planning to do in the web version when using that library? I think these errors are reasonable since the app will break on the web

Comment: I plan to install the web and import and export that instead. Then do a face pattern for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531355/1868008

In your `utilities` directory, create a file named `Intercom.d.ts` and there place the following

```
import DefaultIos from "./Intercom/index.ios";
import * as ios from "./Intercom/index.ios";
import DefaultWeb from "./Intercom/index.web";
import * as web from "./Intercom/index.web";

declare var _test: typeof ios;
declare var _test: typeof web;

declare var _testDefault: typeof DefaultIos;
declare var _testDefault: typeof DefaultWeb;

export * from "./Intercom/index.ios";
export default DefaultIos;
```

Not sure what all those are. Maybe something used in typescript internals.

And for the tests, it seems you'll need to mock every method you use in the  code you're testing, e.g., in this App component; I'm using the `logEvent` method, so I return it in the mock object of the library

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

import App from "./App";
jest.mock("@intercom/intercom-react-native", () => ({ logEvent: jest.fn() }));

describe("<App />", () => {
  it("has 1 child", () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
    expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

App.tsx

```
...
import Intercom from "./utilities/Intercom";

export default function App() {
  Intercom.logEvent("test", {});
   ...
}
```

For the web implementation, you could import the type to ensure compliance with the library interface

```
import type { IntercomType } from "@intercom/intercom-react-native";

const webImplementation: IntercomType = {
  // here implement all methods
};

export default webImplementation;
```

https://github.com/diedu89/expo-isomorphic-import-ts

Comment:  Not only did you show me how to make the `d.ts` file that would be needed, but it also includes a safety trick of how to ensure that the interfaces aren't different between what I do a face-pattern on - that can be handy if I need to implement web. You also included some bonus about jest - thorough research and work has gone into this answer. Thank you very much for that <3

Comment: (the way I could read and understand the `var _test*` is that typescript would complain if you try to redeclare a variable that is different, and it wouldn't if its the same)

Comment: the interface testing does however not seem to work for me. My export from `index.web` does not resemble the export I do from `index.ios` (which is `export { default } from '@intercom/intercom-react-native'`)

Comment: However I do much more like your suggestion for how to ensure compliance (`:IntercomType`)

Comment: @Norfeldt you can check out the repo of the reproduction I made, the web version I have worked for me

Comment: Yes I tried it out and it was very helpful. You done a very good job, thx again